# How do I debug or resolve a 'corrupt x' error when using R map command?

Tags: r

I'm trying to recreate the example in Hadley's *R For Data Science* book (https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html). I can get the first part to work, but when I try to run the map command, I get `Error: Corrupt x: no names`.

Here's the code

```
install.packages("gapminder")
library(gapminder)
gapminder

gapminder %>% 
  ggplot(aes(year, lifeExp, group = country)) +
  geom_line(alpha = 1/3)

by_country <- gapminder %>% 
  group_by(country, continent) %>% 
  nest()
by_country
by_country$data[[1]]

country_model <- function(df) {
  lm(lifeExp ~ year, data = df)
}

models <- map(by_country$data, country_model)
```

Here are all the packages I added

```
library(tidyverse);
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
library(mapdata)
library(maps)
library(viridis)
library(modelr)
```

I was trying to do something similar and kept getting this error, so I decided to exactly what Hadley did and got the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't get any errors with any lines of that code. Do you only get that error on the last line? What versions of the packages listed are you using? If it's the last line you are getting the error on, what version of `purrr` specifically do you have installed?

Comment: Oh wait, you've also loaded `maps` which, like `purrr`, has a function named `map()`. Try `models <- purrr::map(by_country$data, country_model)` to be clear about which one you are calling